# How to delete a remote branch of a submodule (Git)

Tags: git, git-branch, git-submodules

In a Git repository named `Repo` there are 4 submodules:

```
git config --file .gitmodules --name-only --get-regexp path

submodule.A/lib1
submodule.A/lib2 
submodule.lib3 
submodule.lib4
```

Say there is a **remote branch** called `Prototype` on the `lib1` submodule which is no longer needed:

```
git submodule foreach 'git branch -a | grep -i prototype || true'

Entering 'path-to-lib1/lib1'
  remotes/origin/FeatureA
  remotes/origin/Prototype
Entering 'path-to-lib2/lib2'
  remotes/origin/FeatureB
Entering 'path-to-lib3/lib3'
Entering 'path-to-lib4/lib4'
  remotes/origin/FeatureC
```

How can you **delete** this `Prototype` remote branch from the `lib1` submodule?

I tried the following:

```
git push origin --delete Prototype
```

or

```
git push origin --delete origin/Prototype
```

or

```
git push origin --delete remotes/origin/Prototype
```

all 3 above commands give the error:

```
error: unable to delete 'Prototype': remote ref does not exist 
error: failed to push some refs to 'repo-path'
```

(*I am trying to understand the topic of submodules and I have stumbled upon this issue for which I was not able to find the answer following some online search.*)

Any command/suggestion with some explanation will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change directory into the submodule and then `git push --delete origin Prototype`.

Answer (score 1):

You delete the branch in the submodule as a standalone repository, not in the superproject:

```
cd path-to-lib1/lib1
git branch -d Prototype
git push origin --delete Prototype
cd ../..  # back to superproject
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer; I am a bit confused with how your answer (git branch -d Prototype` and then `git push origin --delete Prototype` differs from @Horbas's `git push --delete origin Prototype`. Can you please explain?

Comment: `git branch -d` deletes the branch in your local submodule's repository; `git push --delete` deletes at remote.